# Incorrect datetime value for function str_to_date

Tags: mysql

I can't see what is wrong with this:

```
mysql> select str_to_date('3/8/2010 12:31:00 AM', '%c/%e/%Y %k:%i:%s %p');
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('3/8/2010 12:31:00 AM', '%c/%e/%Y %k:%i:%s %p') |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                   |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Error | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '3/8/2010 12:31:00 AM' for function str_to_date |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
%k:%i:%s %p
```

`%k` is 24-hour clock, doesn't work with `%p` (AM/PM). Use `%l`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mysql> select str_to_date('3/8/2010 12:31:00 AM', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %k');
```